# Can't mint test-collection on mainnet, phantom wallet shows me: "no changes impacting asset ownership found"

Tags: mainnet, phantom-wallet

### **I created this trade because I didn't find any answer**

So, I've deployed test collection on candy machine V3 on mainnet-beta, tried to mint, but phantom wallet shows me: `No changes impacting asset ownership found`.
Does anyone have solution?
[image]